# Add autoloading use-package keywords to a fork of general.el

Tags: use-package, autoload

I have forked [`general.el`](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el) to add a few autoloaded keywords of my own, by using the `:general` keyword use-package functions as a template. However, this bit of code, originally used for `:general`, is not working (read "not being autoloaded"):

```
  (defun use-package-handler/:gone (name _keyword args rest state)
    "Use-package handler for :gone."
    (use-package-concat
     (use-package-process-keywords name rest state)
     `(,@(mapcar (lambda (arglist)
                   ;; Note: prefix commands are not valid functions
                   (if (or (functionp (car arglist))
                           (macrop (car arglist)))
                       `(,@arglist :package ',name)
                     `(general-def (:keymaps '(global aiern-insert-state-map aiern-normal-state-map))
                        ,@arglist
                        :package ',name)))
                 (plist-get args :arglists)))))
```

The part I have changed is the `general-def` bit, by adding `(:keymaps '(global aiern-insert-state-map aiern-normal-state-map))`. When demanding the package, it works fine. Am I missing anything here? I've also copied the `use-package-autoloads/:general` and `use-package-handler/:general` functions as well, which are exactly the same, and renamed them appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found the solution! ... Use the normalizer, handler, and autoloader for `:ghook` instead...

```lisp
  (defun use-package-handler/:gone (name _keyword arglists rest state)
    "Use-package handler for :gone"
    (use-package-concat
     (use-package-process-keywords name rest state)
     `(,@(mapcar (lambda (arglist)
                   arglist
                   `(general-def :keymaps '(global aiern-insert-state-map aiern-normal-state-map) ,@arglist))
                 arglists))))

  (defalias 'use-package-autoloads/:gone #'use-package-autoloads/:ghook)
  (defalias 'use-package-normalize/:gone #'use-package-normalize/:ghook)
```